# Cleanup old nodes

Tags: 6, nodes

How can I mass remove old nodes from drupal-6 by date? I can't find anything on Google or any option for doing that.

The closest module I found are the Revisions to Mass Delete, and the Auto Expire modules.

Answer (score 1):

An option could be creating an *administration page* with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, using filters and [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).